# My if statement in Swift is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I have my random number being printed out so that I can see it but even when the number is zero and I'm pressing the left button it still tells me wrong. 
But it just does it sometimes. Does anyone know what is wrong?
I'm writing with Swift.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var TopLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var LeftImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var RightImageView: UIImageView!
var randomNUmber = arc4random_uniform(2)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ChosePictures()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




@IBAction func Next(_ sender: Any) {
    ChosePictures()
     randomNUmber = arc4random_uniform(2)
}



func ChosePictures()  {

        print(randomNUmber)
        var PictureArrayOne = ["dog", "mushroom", "schedule", "cat"]
        var PictureArrayTwo = ["shower", "chess", "food"]

        let PickedPictureOne = PictureArrayOne[Int(arc4random_uniform(4))]

        let PickedPictureTwo = PictureArrayTwo[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))]

        let PickedPictures = [PickedPictureOne, PickedPictureTwo]
    LeftImageView.image = UIImage(named: PickedPictures[0])
    RightImageView.image = UIImage(named: PickedPictures[1])

    TopLabel.text = PickedPictures[Int(randomNUmber)]

}


@IBAction func LeftButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if randomNUmber == 0{
        TopLabel.text = "Right!"
    }else{
        TopLabel.text = "Wrong"
    }

}





@IBAction func RightButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if randomNUmber == 1{
        TopLabel.text = "Right!"
    }else{
        TopLabel.text = "wrong"
    }


}
```

}

Comment: make sure an action is linked only to one button

Comment: right click on the button and see if its connected to more than one selector; very possible i fyou copied and pasted.

Comment: Checked it and both buttons are only connected to correct code. No double connections.

Comment: Can you please post all the code in your viewcontroller

Comment: Added all of my code to the post

Answer (score 0):

You loading the arc4random only once.

```
@IBOutlet weak var TopLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func LeftButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomNumberResults = arc4random_uniform(2)
    print(randomNumberResults)
    if randomNumberResults == 0 {
        TopLabel.text = "Right!"
    } else {
        TopLabel.text = "Wrong"
    }
}



@IBAction func RightButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomNumberResults = arc4random_uniform(2)
    print(randomNumberResults)
    if randomNumberResults == 1 {
        TopLabel.text = "Right!"
    } else {
        TopLabel.text = "Wrong"
    }

}
```

Are you can do it like this and use a button to reload the arc4

```
var randomNumberResults = Int32()


@IBOutlet weak var TopLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func arc4(_ sender: Any) {
      randomNumberResults = Int32(arc4random_uniform(2))
}

@IBAction func LeftButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(randomNumberResults)
    if randomNumberResults == 0 {
        TopLabel.text = "Right!"
    } else {
        TopLabel.text = "Wrong"
    }
}



@IBAction func RightButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(randomNumberResults)
    if randomNumberResults == 1 {
        TopLabel.text = "Right!"
    } else {
        TopLabel.text = "Wrong"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but that's not my problem. My problem is that even when the random number is 0 and I press the left button it sometimes tells me wrong even do it should say right.